# How can I dynamically decrease by 1 decimal point, regardless of the scale of the number

Tags: python, math

Hi I'd like to have some code in Python where 4.16 can go to 4.15 and 416 can go to 415 and 41600 goes go 41599. How would I do this?

Comment: First, provide a precise mathematical definition of what you want.  Your examples are inconsistent.

Comment: Are these numbers instances of [`decimal.Decimal`?](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#decimal-objects).

Comment: So you want `4.11` to go to `4.1` and `4.1` to go to `4.0` and `4.0` to go to `0.0`, right? Or should `4.0` go to `3.9`? What should `4.10` go to? (And yes, that last one is a trick question.) Can you say a little more about your use-case? It seems like a rather unnatural thing to want to do, and some context might help explain why it's desirable. An answer to @PresidentJamesK.Polk's question would help, too - I can see how this could be made to make sense in the context of `Decimal`, which knows about significant trailing zeros. (And why would `41600` go to `41599` rather than `41500`?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
def decrease_by_1(num):
    is_int = isinstance(num, int)
    count = 0
    while num != int(num):
        num *= 10
        count += 1
    num -= 1
    retval = num / (10 ** count)
    return int(retval) if is_int else retval


print(decrease_by_1(4.16))
print(decrease_by_1(416))
print(decrease_by_1(41600))
```

Result:

```
4.15
415
41599
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way. But wondering what you're really trying to do.

Sound's like a real basic question. Maybe you'd run a tutorial first and start getting into it step by step.

```
from decimal import Decimal

a = 4.16
b = 416
c = 41600

print(type(a))
print(type(b))
print(type(c))

x = Decimal(a) - Decimal(0.01)
print(round(x, 2))
print(b - 1)
print(c - 1)
```

Result:

```
<class 'float'>
<class 'int'>
<class 'int'>
4.15
415
41599
```

Answer (score 0):

Using some strings manipulation would achieve what you need (even if not a numerical solution - and yes, I would really be curious myself what the purpose of this is):

```
def sub(n):
    ns = str(n)
    i = ns.index(".") if "." in ns else -1
    ns = str(int(ns.replace(".","")) - 1)
    res = ("." if i > -1 else "").join([ns[:i], ns[i:]])
    return float(res) if i > -1 else int(res)

print(sub(4.15))
print(sub(416)) 
print(sub(41600))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
4.14
415
41599
```

Answer (score 0):

You could convert to a string replacing all digits with zeroes except the last one (which you replace by 1) then use that as a numeric of the same type to subtract the appropriately scaled 1:

```
def dec1(n):
    zero = str.maketrans("123456789","0"*9)
    return n-type(n)(str(n).translate(zero)[:-1]+"1")
```

Output:

```
for n in (4.16,416,41600,-2.5):
    print(n,dec1(n))

4.16 4.15
416 415
41600 41599
-2.5 -2.4
```

*Keep in mind that if you intend to use this repeatedly on a number with more than 1 decimal positions, the scale will go up after processing a value ending  by 1:*

*4.22 -> 4.21 -> 4.2 -> 4.1 -> 4.0 -> 3.9*